# How to bulk update Manager for many users on AzureAD using .csv imported?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I have a .csv with 2 columns: UserPrincipalName and Manager. I would like to import this .csv and bulk update the Manager attribute for users based on their UserPrincipalName.

Please help with the PowerShell script for this. Please note that this is fully an AzureAD, not On-PremAD.

Thank you.

Here is the script I tried,

```
#importing the CSV source which has the changes 
$data = Import-Csv C:\Users\LongTran\Desktop\TW\List\manager2.csv

#Iterating through each row in the CSV
foreach ($row in $data)
{
#INFO in the Console
Write-Host "Updating the user :"  $row.'User Username'    " manager to "  $row.'Manager Username'  -ForegroundColor Yellow 

#Updating the Manager 
Set-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username').Objectid -RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'Manager Username').Objectid

#Completion info in the console for the specified row
Write-Host "Updated." -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Have no idea why I executed this script, it always show error:

```
Get-AzureADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null.
At line:11 char:61
+ ... ger -ObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $row.'User Username').Object ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzureADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetUser
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a peer to peer forum where coders help other coders voluntarily with their challenges. It is not a free script shop. So please at least take the [Tour] and stop by on the help topic [Ask] to set your expectations. Thanks in advance. 

Comment: Could you include more details like what you tried and where you stuck by editing your question with code and error details?

Comment: @Rukmini sorry, first time trying Stack Overflow, and I really a rookie on PowerShell. Already edited the script I found and tried before asking here, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path "path to your .csv file"

#for every user in collection
foreach ($user in $users) {
    #get manager's ID
    $managerID = (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq $user.Manager").ObjectID
    #set a manager for UserPrincipalName
    Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq $user.UserPrincipalName" | Set-AzureADUserManager -RefObjectId $managerID
```

}

Unfortunately, I don't have access to AzureAD to check the script.

Comment: Don't you feel like you just did someones homework now?  

Comment: quite possible :)

Comment: @Re1ter well, appreciate your help. however, everyone start from 0-to-1, right? I'm new to PowerShell and first time trying Stack Overflow. Sry if it my question bothered you. I will try the your script and update if it works for me.

I'm a little bit confusing between some values and how/when to use them e.g.: Get-ADUser and Get-AzureADUSer, -Filter...etc

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I found out the issue is from my CSV file: in the Manager column, I input the "Display Name" of the "Manager User" => replaced them with the "UserPrinciPalName" of the "Manager User" => worked properly.

Also used this script to run the updated successfully.

Thanks, all!

```
$CSVrecords = Import-Csv C:\Users\LongTran\Desktop\TW\List\wronguser.csv -Delimiter ","

foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
$usr = $CSVrecord.UserPrincipalName
$manager = $CSVrecord.Manager
$user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$usr'"
$Managerobj = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userprincipalname eq '$manager'"

if ($user) 
{
 try{
 $user | Set-AzureADUserManager -RefObjectid $Managerobj.objectid
} 
catch {
   $FailedUsers += $usr
Write-Warning "$usr user found, but FAILED to update."
  }
 }
  else {
   Write-Warning "$usr not found, skipped"
$SkippedUsers += $usr
  }
 }
```